# Search and Inserting in a binary tree recursively

Tags: c, recursion, tree

first of all happy new year. I was trying to fix a piece of code I've been stumped on for hours. (Note: I am not a solid coder.)

What I am trying to do is to write a function "searchInsert", which will take in a binary tree and some integer i. It will then try to find the integer i in the tree. If it's not there it is inserted into the tree.

Other information: If we do in fact find the integer in the tree, return a pointer pointing to the node of to it. If we do not find it as we said before, insert it in BUT return a pointer pointing to the **root** of the tree.

I also must do this recursively.

Now I have tested it using an arbitrary tree along with i = 98, as follows:

Before what it looks like.

```
     4
    / \
   2   6
  / \ / \
 1  3 5  7
```

After, what it should look like:

```
     4
    / \
   2   6
  / \ / \
 1  3 5  7
          \
          98
```

But my code doesn't seem to be working.

```
treelink searchInsert(treelink t, TreeItem i){

    treelink keyNode = NULL;
    if (t == NULL) {
        t = insertTreeNode(t, i);  
    } else if(i < t->item){
        keyNode = searchInsert(t->left,i); 
    } else if(i > t->item){
        keyNode = searchInsert(t->right,i);   
    } else {
        keyNode = t;
        return keyNode;
    }    

    return t;
 }
```

Other important notes: treelink is a pointer to a binary tree. Assume insertTreeNode works as it was a function given to us.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: One thing I notice immediately is that it's at least weird (if not incorrect) is that `keyNode` is assigned but never used in two of the conditional blocks. I think it's worth re-examining your logic. Also, can you show us what the tree actually looks like after running your function?

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to be working" mean, specifically?

Comment: Cmd - yeah you are correct, my brain doesn't seem to be working.

@Scott, when running the code with some tests. I tried the given tree, and i = 98. It didn't seem to have inserted into the tree at all.

I suspect it's something to with my returns.

Comment: Please clarify what the arguments to `insertTreeNode` should be.  Does it take the root of the tree, or the branch where it should be inserted?  or something else altogether?

Comment: It takes a root of a tree, and an item to search. It returns the root of the new tree after insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems, you have lost all context when you realize that you have not found the item that you are looking for:

```
if ( t == NULL ) {
  t = insertTreeNode(t, i) ;
}
```

So you are always calling `insertTreeNode` with `NULL` as the first argument.

While recursion is a great way to step through a tree, you might instead want to create a pointer and iterate through the tree, so that you have the original `t` around when you decide to call insert.

```
{
  treelink ptr= t ;
  while ( ptr )
  {
    if ( ptr-> item == i ) return ptr ;
    ptr= ( ptr-> item > i ) ? ptr-> left : ptr-> right ;
  }

  return insertTreeNode( t, i ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new node is created, but it is not linked to the tree. You never change your `left` and `right` pointers.

what you need is to update the link after recursive call, e.g.:

```
else if (i < t->item) {
    t->left = searchInsert(t->left, i);
} ...
```

But then of course you cannot simply return a pointer to a *found* item if it's found, otherwise it would break the tree. That's because the statement of your task is NOT recursive: you have to return either root or an existing (inner) node. So you might want to write a recursive function which e.g. always returns a pointer to the root, but also returns a pointer to a found item (through an additional `treelink*` argument).

Or maybe it would be simpler to split the function into two: `search` which returns a pointer to an existing node, and `insert` which returns a pointer to the root. Both of them would be recursive and quite simple.